# JSON to C# object is failing

Tags: json

I am having some difficulty converting my json data to C# object. Following is my JSON

```
{
   "payload": [{
           "product": {
               "id": "ATEDXX"
           }

       },
       {
           "product": {
               "id": "CTBB"
           }

       }
   ]
}
```

Following is the class

```
public class product
   {
    public string id { get; set; }
   }
```

And following is the serialization

```
public class Record
        {
            public List<product> payload { get; set; }
        }

 var myProd =  (Record)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(resultContent,typeof(Record));
```

I can see two records are deserialized into "myProd" variable but the "id" is always null.
Not sure what am I doing wrong. I tried it with and without the Json/DataContract attributes to the property and pretty much all other things.

Any help greatly appreciated.
thanks

Comment: Check out http://json2csharp.com/ or https://app.quicktype.io/#l=cs&r=json2csharp It does all this work for you, in your case I believe it's because Record only has Payload has different cases for the name and you have to specify that in the options for the serializer using `[JsonProperty("product")]` and `[JsonProperty("id")]`

Comment: Thanks! That helped. Didn't need any jsonproperty attribs. The class generated by this site did the trick!